# Why does ls show one directory in a different color?

Tags: bash, command-line, terminal

I adjusted my .bash_profile so that when I use the `ls` command, the contents of a folder are color coded.  Every directory I can find is printed in bold blue, except for one, which is simply highlighted in yellow.  Are there different types of directories?  Typing `file strangedir` tells me the directory in question is just a directory.  These are the lines in .bash_profile that I changed:

```
export PS1="\[\033[36m\]\u\[\033[m\]@\[\033[32m\]\h:\[\033[33;1m\]\w\[\033[m\]\$ "
export CLICOLOR=1;
export LSCOLORS=ExGxBxDxCxEgEdxbxgxcxd;
alias ls='ls -GFh'
```

Here is the stuff in the folder:

```
aaronparisi@aarons-MacBook-Pro:~/Desktop/Seattle$ ls -l
total 1984
drwxr-xr-x   4 aaronparisi  staff   136B Sep 30  2017 AI/
-rw-r--r--@  1 aaronparisi  staff   148K Dec 19  2015 Apt list.pages
drwxr-xr-x   9 aaronparisi  staff   306B Nov  4  2017 Fall 2017/
drwxr-xr-x   7 aaronparisi  staff   238B Oct  8  2017 Round Two/
-rw-r--r--@  1 aaronparisi  staff   401K Dec 21  2015 Scan.pdf
drwxr-xr-x   6 aaronparisi  staff   204B Jan 12  2016 Spring 2016/
drwxr-xr-x   5 aaronparisi  staff   170B May 10  2016 Summer 2016/
-rw-r--r--@  1 aaronparisi  staff   133K Jun  4 16:33 aaron parisi suletter.docx
-rw-r--r--@  1 aaronparisi  staff    42K Jun  4 16:33 aaron parisi suletter.pdf
drwxr-xr-x   7 aaronparisi  staff   238B Mar  1  2017 hacking?/
drwxr-xr-x   9 aaronparisi  staff   306B Oct 10  2017 html+css/
-rw-r--r--@  1 aaronparisi  staff   256K Dec 20  2015 lease-agreement.pdf
drwxr-xr-x  34 aaronparisi  staff   1.1K Mar 25 15:38 leet code/
drwxrwxrwx@  7 aaronparisi  staff   238B May 30 09:56 python/
drwxr-xr-x  20 aaronparisi  staff   680B Sep 22  2017 terminal-game-tutorial/
```

The folder in question is the one called python/

Comment: run `ls -l` and paste the result in your question.

Comment: LSCOLORS defines the colours for a variety of files. It's likely the yellow directory is a symbolic link, or possibly a socket, pipe, executable or any other of the types listed here: https://geoff.greer.fm/lscolors/

You can play around with changing LSCOLORS there, too, and see what happens to the output.

Comment: What does `ls -ld "$(readlink python)"` print?

Comment: It's a MacBook, seems that folder has [extended attributes](https://superuser.com/questions/155458/what-does-the-mean-on-the-output-of-ls-on-os-x-terminal). Use `ls -le`to show them. In your sample, it's the only directory with an at sign in its permissions.

Comment: `chmod 644 python`?

Comment: It's just because it's world writable (i.e. `o+w`). The color is to remind you not to trust anything in it.

Answer (score 2):

Found a couple similar posts with nice answers on it:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/17299/what-do-the-different-colors-mean-in-ls

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/94498/what-causes-this-green-background-in-ls-output

Here's the information from the post:

- Blue: Directory
- Green: Executable or recognized data file
- Sky Blue: Symbolic link file
- Yellow with black background: Device
- Pink: Graphic image file
- Red: Archive file
- Red with black background: Broken link

Also, found this link which gives some help on setting different colours for different kinds of files when using the ls command:

http://linux-sxs.org/housekeeping/lscolors.html

Answer (score 1):

I had 3 folders which were shown with Yellow color in the terminal.

The issue was with permissions. It had 777 permission i.e. drwxrwxrwx.

I changed it to 755 i.e. drwxr-xr-x recursively using

`sudo chmod -R 755 directory`

and it turned into a normal directory.